# Remove all instances of duplicates in SAS

Tags: sas

I am merging two SAS datasets by ID number and would like to remove all instances of duplicate IDs, i.e. if an ID number occurs twice in the merged dataset then **both** observations with that ID will be deleted.

Web searches have suggested some sql methods and nodupkey, but these are not working because they are for typical duplicate cleansing where one instance is kept and then the multiples are deleted.

Comment: Are you merging (adding columns) or appending (adding rows)?

Comment: Why is this tagged "sql"?

Comment: This question would be better if you provided example of before and after in data.

Comment: Thank to all responders.  I appended instead of merged because as Pekka pointed out, merging would conceal inter-dataset duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using a DATA step with a BY id; statement, then adding:

```
if NOT (first.id and last.id) then delete;
```

should do it.  If that doesn't work, please show your code.

I'm actually a fan of writing dropped records to a separate dataset so you can track how many records were dropped at different points.  So I would code this something like:

```
data want
     drop_dups
;
  merge a b ;
  by id ;
  if first.id and last.id then output want ;
  else output drop_dups ;
run ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an SQL way to do it. You can use left/right/inner join best suitable for your needs. Note that this works on a single dataset just as well.

```
proc sql;
    create table singles as 
    select * from dataset1 a inner join dataset2 b
    on a.ID = b.ID
    group by a.ID
    having count(*) = 1;
quit;
```

For example from

```
ID  x
5   2
5   4
1   6
2   7
3   6
```

You will select

```
ID  x
1   6
2   7
3   6
```