# Keeping or deleting a group of observations based on a characteristic of a BY-group

Tags: sas

I answered a SAS question a few minutes ago and realized there is a generalization that might be more useful than that one ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40541843/sas-proc-sql-remove-all-observations-in-by-group-as-long-as-there-are-duplicat)). I didn't see this question already in StackOverflow.

The general question is: How can you process and keep an entire BY-group based on some characteristic of the BY-group that you might not know until you have looked at all the observations in the group?

Using input data similar to that from the earlier question:

```
* For some reason, we are tasked with keeping only observations that
* are in groups of ID_1 and ID_2 that contain at least one obs with
* a VALUE of 0.;
* In the following data, the following ID and ID_2 groups should be
* kept:
* A 2 (2 obs)
* B 1 (3 obs)
* B 3 (2 obs)
* B 4 (1 obs)
* The resulting dataset will have 8 observations.;
data x;
    input id $ id_2 value;
datalines;
A 1 1
A 1 1
A 1 1
A 2 0
A 2 1
B 1 0
B 1 1
B 1 3
B 2 1
B 3 0
B 3 0
B 4 0
C 2 4
;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double DoW loop solution:

```
data have;
    input id $ id_2 value;
datalines;
A 1 1
A 1 1
A 1 1
A 2 0
A 2 1
B 1 0
B 1 1
B 1 3
B 2 1
B 3 0
B 3 0
B 4 0
C 2 4
;
run;

data want;
do _n_ = 1 by 1 until(last.id_2);
    set have;
    by id id_2;
    flag = sum(flag,value=0);
end;
do _n_ = 1 to _n_;
    set have;
    if flag then output;
end;
drop flag;
run;
```

I've tested this against the `point` approach using ~55m rows and found no appreciable difference in performance. Dataset used:

```
data have;
do ID = 1 to 10000000;
    do id_2 = 1 to ceil(ranuni(1)*10);
        do value = floor(ranuni(2) * 5);
            output;
        end;
    end;
end;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you and thanks to @Reeza for introducing me to the DoW loop.

Comment: Oops, missed the editing time limit. Anyway, @user667489, your code works, and I appreciate the elegance, but I think it is not the most efficient. Because the specs say that we either keep or reject the entire by-group, it is not necessary to iterate through the **have** dataset twice. That's why I used the **POINT=** option so it only accesses the second **SET** statement when it is needed. I also have a question: Is **SUM(flag,value=0)** more efficient than an **IF** statement and a simple assignment of 1 to **flag**?

Comment: I suspect you'll find that the extra full sequential read costs the same or less vs. random access via `point`. `sum` is convenient here as it defaults missing values to 0 at the start of each by-group.

Comment: I checked a stripped-down version of sequential read (a **DATA _NULL_**, **SET**, and **RUN**) against a stripped-down DoW loop (same code except **SET x END=EOF** in a loop ending when EOF is true). I ran it on ~135M observations, and the traditional sequential read consistently took 7% longer than the DoW loop data step. So it looks like DoW is inherently a little more efficient than the traditional approach, probably because of things like creating the PDV every time.

Comment: I also compared the efficiency of sequential **SET** against **SET** with the **POINT=** option. Again using ~135M obs, the direct-access method took **more than 3x** the time that the sequential method took. Obviously, that would not be recommended for resource-intensive processes.

Answer (score 1):

My answer might not be the most efficient, especially for large datasets, and I'm interested in seeing other possible answers. Here it is:

```
* For some reason, we are tasked with keeping only observations that
* are in groups of ID_1 and ID_2 that contain at least one obs with
* a VALUE of 0.;
* In the following data, the following ID and ID_2 groups should be
* kept:
* A 2 (2 obs)
* B 1 (3 obs)
* B 3 (2 obs)
* B 4 (1 obs)
* The resulting dataset will have 8 observations.;
data x;
    input id $ id_2 value;
datalines;
A 1 1
A 1 1
A 1 1
A 2 0
A 2 1
B 1 0
B 1 1
B 1 3
B 2 1
B 3 0
B 3 0
B 4 0
C 2 4
;
run;

* I realize the data are already sorted, but I think it is better
* not to assume they are.;
proc sort data=x;
    by id id_2;
run;

data obstokeep;
    keep id id_2 value;
    retain startptr haszero;

    * This SET statement reads through the dataset in sequence and 
    * uses the CUROBS option to obtain the observation number. In
    * most situations, this will be the same as the _N_ automatic
    * variable, but CUROBS is probably safer.;
    set x curobs=myptr;
    by id id_2;

    * When this is the first observation in a BY-group, save the 
    * current observation number (pointer).
    * Also initialize a flag variable that will become 1 if any 
    * obs contains a VALUE of 0; 
    * The variables are in a RETAIN statement, so they keep their
    * values as the SET statement above is executed for each obs
    * in the BY-group.;
    if first.id_2
     then do;
        startptr=myptr;
        haszero=0;
     end;

    * This statement is executed for each observation. We check
    * whether VALUE is 0 and, if so, record that fact.;
    if value = 0
     then haszero=1;

    * At the end of the BY-group, we check to see if there were
    * any observations with VALUE = 0. If so, we go back using
    * another SET statement, re-read them via direct access, and
    * write them to the output dataset.
    * (Note that if VALUE order is not relevant, you can gain a bit
    * more efficiency by writing the current obs first, then going
    * back to get the rest.);
    if last.id_2 and haszero
     then do;
        * When LAST and FIRST at the same time, there is only one
        * obs, so no need to backtrack, just output and go on.;
        if first.id_2
         then output obstokeep;
         else do;
            * Here we assume that the observations are sequential
            * (which they will be for a sequential SET statement),
            * so we re-read these observations using another SET 
            * statement with the POINT option for direct access 
            * starting with the first obs of the by-group (the 
            * saved pointer) and ending with the current one (the
            * current pointer).;
            do i=startptr to myptr;
              set x point=i;
              output obstokeep;
            end;
         end;
     end;

run;
```

Comment: You should look into a DoW loop http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings09/038-2009.pdf

Answer (score 0):

```
proc sql;
   select a.*,b.value from (select id,id_2 from have where value=0)a left join have b
   on a.id=b.id and a.id_2=b.id_2;
quit;
```

Comment: Thank you for this SQL solution. However, it has a slight problem. It returns too many rows because sometimes the BY-group has more than one row with **value=0**.  In this case, it returned two extra rows for **id="B", id_2=3**.  I tweaked it so it works:  `code`proc sql;
   select a.id, a.id_2 ,b.value
 from (select id, id_2, count(*)
   from have 
   where value=0
   group by id, id_2) a 
  left join 
 have b
   on a.id=b.id and a.id_2=b.id_2;
quit;`code`

Comment: I checked efficiency by running this and @user667489's code on 27.5 million rows, and PROC SQL took 51.49 (21.01 CPU) seconds versus only 13.37 (4.87 CPU) seconds for the double DoW approach. PROC SQL was sorting the data, which might account for a lot of the difference.